# Creating a meter UI for memory usage

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

In my Android app I would like to show the memory availability to the end user with the help of a graphical meter (similar to the one in the Android settings)

[image]

Can anyone suggest the best UI component I can use for developing this kind of UI. I tried few samples with the progress bar but it didn't solve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one Linear Layout in which multiple linearLayouts are divided through weights.

like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#fff333"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="#fff333" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            android:background="#80DAE4" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            android:background="#80E487" >
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            android:background="#80A3E4" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="#E4B980" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice approach. quite simple only one thing that we actually don't even need so many `LinearLayouts` just one `LinearLayout` as container and the child layouts can be `Views` instead with desired background color.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use one of many graphic libraries available for Android (I don't know which one exactly but I am quite sure there exists one for this purpose and can't remember the name). Yes, you can create a layout like this, but filling data in and changing widths will be totally ridiculous. Have a look at these libraries and see if you can find a suitable one
[Graphics libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40) 
[William Chart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart)